# Android NDK error: cannot declare reference to cv::InputArray

Tags: c++, opencv, android-ndk

I have my code written in C++ using OpenCV library and tested on VS C++ 2010. Now I want to use that code in an Android project. For this purpose, I use the latest revision of Android NDK and OpenCV4Android sdk. But when I try the `ndk-build` command, this error happen:

```
error: cannot declare a reference to 'cv::InputArray {aka const class cv::_InputArray&}'
```

Yes, I did use InputArray datatype from OpenCV in my C++ code, and this is the line where the error occurs:

```
unsigned int someFunction(const InputArray &);
```

And I know, in OpenCV, the InputArray is defined as:

```
typedef const _InputArray& InputArray;
```

On VS C++, it compiled and worked without any warning. But I don't know how to make it work on Android NDK. Note that I do NOT use Cygwin but the default `ndk-build` script shipped with Android NDK for compilation (does it matter?). Please someone provide me with some guideline to accomplish this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `InputArray` as is without references:

```
unsigned int someFunction(InputArray);
```

As you mentioned `InputArray` is already a typedef for reference. And as I remember C++ doesn't allow to declare reference to reference. Visual Studio might be an exception.